# How can I prevent duplicates in my MS SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a PowerShell Script who writes data from the Eventviewer into a MS SQL database.

```
$events = Get-WinEvent @{LogName = "System"; ID = 4720,4726,4741,4743,4727,4730,4728,4729,4740,4767} | Select-Object ID, MachineName, Message, TimeCreated  

$connectionString = "Data Source=Server\INSTANZ;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Database;"
$bulkCopy = new-object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $connectionString
$bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Table"
$dt = New-Object "System.Data.DataTable"

# build the datatable
$cols = $events | select -first 1 | get-member -MemberType NoteProperty | select -Expand Name
foreach ($col in $cols)  {$null = $dt.Columns.Add($col)}

foreach ($event in $events)
  {
     $row = $dt.NewRow()
     foreach ($col in $cols) { $row.Item($col) = $event.$col }
     $dt.Rows.Add($row)
  }

 # Write to the database!
 $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($dt)
```

The MS SQL database has the rows ID, MachineName, Message and TimeCreated.

When I run the script for the first time it works perfectly. When I run the script again it writes all data into the database again.

How can I only write the differents between the two runs?

Comment: Can you add the rest of the code which shows us how you're writing to the database? Sounds like you need to perform a merge statement or check for the existence of the values you're trying to write into the database. If they exist, update (or don't insert), otherwise insert.

Comment: Merge or Select your new values LEFT JOIN to your destination table where the business keys don't yet exist.

Comment: I updated the code!

Comment: @TheD I guess trigger will help you in that case, please, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create INSTEAD OF trigger on your table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SomeTriggerName
ON YourTableName
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
MERGE YourTable as t
USING inserted as i
ON i.ID= t.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT VALUES (ID, MachineName, Message, TimeCreated)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET MachineName = i.MachineName,
                Message = i.Message,
                TimeCreated = i.TimeCreated
```

Or you can use MERGE directly, instead of INSERTion:

```
MERGE YourTable as t
USING inserted as i
ON i.ID= t.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT VALUES (ID, MachineName, Message, TimeCreated)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET MachineName = i.MachineName,
                Message = i.Message,
                TimeCreated = i.TimeCreated
```

Comment: I like your second suggestion but the first one is horrible. With triggers like that, an insert statement can update rows, which leads to no end of confusion.

Comment: @Andomar There is no UPDATE in that trigger it will only insert rows, because I don't know what OP want to do with that one. Personally I prefer using MERGE without any triggers it i more clear.

Comment: You're right, so your trigger silently discards INSERTs for rows whose ID already exists. You can see how confusing triggers are :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sql to do this

You will need to identify what columns in your sql table make your records unique

Then do a sql insert while checking the records don't already exist, using your unique key